# Node.js json2csv output not aligned properly

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I am using json2csv package to convert the queried data to csv and allow the user to download the file. Everything works fine, except that the output header and the corresponding data are not aligned properly. This is what I get
[image]

But this is what I need.
[image]

**Code:**

```
var fields = ['firstname', 'surname']
Users.find().select().exec(function(err, users){
    json2csv({data: users, fields: fields}, function(err, csv){
        if(err)
            console.log(err)
        else{
            var filename = 'users.csv'
            var mimetype = 'application/csv'

            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename)
            res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype)
            res.end(csv)
        }
    })
})
```

How to align the headers and the data properly in their columns? Thanks

**EDIT:**
CSV output in the browser console.

[image]

Comment: please post the users json too

Comment: @PeterPorfy Please see the edit....

Comment: are you sure that this is not an import problem? can you show me the csv in a text editor?

Comment: @PeterPorfy To be honest I am not sure what the problem is. The first image http://i.stack.imgur.com/xsw1W.jpg is the actual csv.

Comment: the first screenshot seems like a spreadsheet software, can you post the output csv?

Comment: @PeterPorfy Sorry for that. Please see now

Comment: It seems ok to me. What spreadsheet software are you using? It seems to me that this is a csv import problem, the export seems fine.

Comment: It seems to me that you simply just import the CSV the wrong way - you lack to set `,` as delimiter when you load the CSV - your reader assumes `;`. It is not `json2csv` that is the error here, but your use of the reader afterwards :)

Comment: @PeterPorfy Just now noticed. it works well on Excel and messes up on the Openoffice.

Answer (score 1):

json2csv have option

> quotes - String, quotes around cell values and column names. Defaults to " if not specified.

you can try to set empty space or some one else instead quotes